# Unknown issue affecting print quality

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, extrusion, asa, flashforge-creator

I have been having issues with a vase print using a FlashForge Creator Pro. 
I am using the default slicer for the printer(FlashPrint) because the Creator Pro only accepts `.x3g` rather than `.g`/`.gcode`.

The issue is that the printer seems to be both under extruding and over extruding.

[image: Under and Over Extrusion]

I am printing ASA filament at 0.18 mm layer height at 240 °C with a heated bed at 110 °C. I am running the print with the fan on. I am also running at 80 mm/s print speed.

I have tried both lowering and raising the temperature, changing the print speed from 80 mm/s to 60 mm/s, and changing the extrusion multiplier.

At this point I am not really sure what to do in order to get this to print nicely, any advice would be welcome.

---

After a few more prints and the link that "E-Doe" posted I am beginning to think that the problem might be with the z-axis. My reason for thinking this is that the layers that bulge out do so consistently for the entire layer and then stop for a bit. I think I also ruled out temperature variation. I measured the temperature in the enclosure with a separate device and it stayed pretty constant the whole time.

Not really sure how to fix that but I will call this question answered.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing!

Comment: What is your nozzle size?

Comment: The nozzle is 0.4mm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very helpful page for troubleshooting common errors is: [Print Quality Troubleshooting Guide](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/) - [Lines on the Side of Print](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/#lines-on-the-side-of-print)

It seems like your problem is inconsistent extrusion or temperature variation. From the photo you posted I guess that you use a big diameter nozzle. Keep in mind that your extruder might not be well equipped to deliver such a large amount of plastic consistently. This most likely is a problem with the heating capacity.

You can try to lower the speed even more to give your extruder more time to heat the plastic.

Comment: To elaborate, over extrusion is at the points where movement will be slow, under extrusion occurs in the longer travel where speed will be higher.

Comment: It is odd though because the under extrusion is in the spots where it should be going slower. the tips of the walls should be going slower than the rest. Also the over extrusion happens for 1 full layer. and then stops for a bit.

Comment: @Sean It is not that odd. The printer will adjust its plastic output when the speed is altered, so you won't see any changes between slow and fast parts of the prints. When the temperature drops, the viscosity of the plastic decreases, which leads to less material output. This leads to a longer time in the melting chamber, which leads to a higher temperature -> higher viscosity -> more plastic output. Rinse and repeat.